# Show column names having null values in row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I would like to display only those column name against the student id whose question(q1,q2,q3,q4...etc) value is null below is the printscreen of table against the id i would like to have question id . with below expected o/p

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your expected result.

Comment: do you want to list out all those students who are having null in all the questions? or do you want to list out them if they have null in at least one question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FOR XML` to achieve the result:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c3b5e/1/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT id, name, q = 'q1' FROM Test WHERE q1 IS NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT id, name, q = 'q2' FROM Test WHERE q2 IS NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT id, name, q = 'q3' FROM Test WHERE q3 IS NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT id, name, q = 'q4' FROM Test WHERE q4 IS NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT id, name, q = 'q5' FROM Test WHERE q5 IS NULL UNION ALL
    SELECT id, name, q = 'q6' FROM Test WHERE q6 IS NULL
)
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    incompletes = STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + c2.q
        FROM Cte c2
        WHERE
            c1.id = c2.id
            AND c1.name = c2.name
        GROUP BY c2.id, c2.name, c2.q
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
        , 1, 1, '')
FROM Cte c1
GROUP BY c1.id, c1.name
ORDER BY c1.id, c1.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID, NAME, 
 RTRIM ((CASE WHEN Q1 IS NULL THEN 'Q1,' END)||
        (CASE WHEN Q2 IS NULL THEN 'Q2,' END)||
        (CASE WHEN Q3 IS NULL THEN 'Q3,' END)||
        (CASE WHEN Q4 IS NULL THEN 'Q4,' END)||
        (CASE WHEN Q5 IS NULL THEN 'Q5,' END)||
        (CASE WHEN Q6 IS NULL THEN 'Q6,' END),',') AS NULL_QUESTIONS
FROM TABLE
```

---

*EDIT: Added `STUFF` to get rid of the leading comma and added `ELSE ''`:*

```
SELECT ID, NAME,  
    STUFF (
        CASE WHEN Q1 IS NULL THEN ',q1' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN Q2 IS NULL THEN ',q2' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN Q3 IS NULL THEN ',q3' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN Q4 IS NULL THEN ',q4' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN Q5 IS NULL THEN ',q5' ELSE '' END +
        CASE WHEN Q6 IS NULL THEN ',q6' ELSE '' END
    , 1,1,'') AS NULL_QUESTIONS
FROM Test
```

Comment: Nice solution. +1. Please see my edit. Feel free to revert it if you want.

Comment: i am finding issue with both this query it is showing me only first 6 question no. so when i opened my table structure i found collation Latin1_General_CI_AI on all other columns  is this data not displayed cbecause of collation??

Comment: You will have to manually add entries for the number of question columns in your table.
Thanks wewesthemenace for correcting the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Panelist_ID, EmailAddress collate Latin1_General_CI_AI,  
STUFF (
  CASE WHEN  convert (nvarchar (14), PQ_160175) IS NULL THEN ',PQ_160175'    ELSE '' END +
 CASE WHEN  convert (nvarchar (14), PQ_161979) IS NULL THEN ',PQ_161979'  ELSE '' END +
  CASE WHEN  convert (nvarchar (14), PQ_161980) IS NULL THEN ',PQ_161980'  ELSE '' END +
  CASE WHEN  convert (nvarchar (14), PQ_161981) IS NULL THEN ',PQ_161981'  ELSE '' END +
  CASE WHEN  convert (nvarchar (14), PQ_161982) IS NULL THEN ',PQ_161982'  ELSE '' END +
 CASE WHEN  convert (nvarchar (14), PQ_161983) IS NULL THEN ',PQ_161983'  ELSE '' END +
   CASE WHEN    convert (nvarchar (14), PQ_161986) IS NULL THEN ',PQ_161986'     ELSE '' END +
   CASE WHEN   PQ_172469 IS NULL THEN ',PQ_172469'  ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN   PQ_180972 IS NULL THEN ',PQ_180972'  ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN PQ_180973 IS NULL THEN ',PQ_180973'  ELSE '' END + 
      CASE WHEN PQ_189924 IS NULL THEN ',PQ_189924'  ELSE '' END +
     CASE WHEN PQ_195859 IS NULL THEN ',PQ_195859'  ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN PQ_195860 IS NULL THEN ',PQ_195860'  ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN PQ_196605 IS NULL THEN ',PQ_196605'  ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN PQ_196606 IS NULL THEN ',PQ_196606'  ELSE '' )
```

i have been using the aboce case statement and i am not able to see the output after 161983 nos

[image]